# How to bind onloadeddata event in Ionic Framework

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Is there a way to determine which source was used when specifying multiple sources to an HTML5 audio/video element in Ionic Framework?

I use next element:

```
<audio controls controlsList="noplaybackrate nodownload">
    <source [src]="story.file_url" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source [src]="story.file_url2" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source [src]="story.file_url3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I need to know which of source is outdated now.
I tried to register onload and onloadeddata event handlers on the source elements but they where never called. Also src of the audio element is unchanged after load and the source elements don't have a readyState property.